# Passed string become empty in gdb?

Tags: c++, string, gdb, instantiation

I have the following code:

```
CrowdSim::Simulation my_simulation;
void printstring(std::string filename)
{
  std::cerr<<"filename= " <<filename<<std::endl;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

  std::vector<std::string> tokens;
  std::string filename = "";
  if(argc > 1)
  {
    std::string args(argv[1]);
    split(tokens, args, is_any_of("\"="), token_compress_on);
    filename = tokens.at(1);
  }

  my_simulation = CrowdSim::Simulation();
  printstring(filename);
```

I run the program with the following

```
./CrowdSim -filename="Layout/layout_1"
```

Within gdb, I put a breakpoint right before `printstring(filename)`. When hitting this breakpoint, I execute `print filename`, and the output is `"Layout/layout_1"`. Immediately after entering `printstring` (stepping in with `step`), I `print filename` and the result is `""`.

However, if I actually let the next line run, the output is fine: it prints `filename= Layout/layout_1`. Is this some sort of gdb error? It's making it very hard to debug without using a ton of `cerr` statements. What could be causing this?

Additionally, if I comment out all lines involving `my_simulation` (so that it never gets initialized and I never use it) I get an error upon stepping into `printstring`:

```
printstring (filename=Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/gdb/python/libstdcxx/v6/printers.py", line 469, in to_string
    return self.val['_M_dataplus']['_M_p'].string (encoding, length = len)
RuntimeError: Error reading string from inferior: Input/output error
) at Source/main.cc:13
```

I also tested this with a program which contains only the above `main` and `printstring` functions, with no references to any other objects. The above error still occurs.

Can anyone explain either of these errors to me? Also, somewhat related, in c++, does the line `CrowdSim::Simulation my_simulation`automatically call the constructor, so that I no longer need the line `my_simulation = ...`? In Java, declaring a variable doesn't construct it (as far as I know), so both lines are usually necessary (I think).

Comment: The string thing: are you compiling with all optimization off?  Even if you are, such behaviour from debuggers is not that unusual.

Comment: Yes variable is likely to be optimised out. Try compiling with `-O0 -g3`. Variable declaration calls its default constructor, if it is defined.